# ConcurrentDictionary AddOrUpdate a list

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda, concurrentdictionary

I'm trying to use a ConcurrentDictionary to help with a filtering task.

If a number appears in list, then I want to copy an entry from one dictionary to another.

But this part of the AddOrUpdate is not right -  `v.Add(number)`

I get

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

And two more errors.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        List<int> filter = new List<int> {1,2};
        p.Filter(filter);
    }


    private void Filter(List<int> filter)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> unfilteredResults = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
        unfilteredResults.Add("key1", new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5});

        ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<int>> filteredResults = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<int>>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> unfilteredResult in unfilteredResults)
        {
            foreach (int number in unfilteredResult.Value)
            {
                if (filter.Contains(number))
                {
                    filteredResults.AddOrUpdate(unfilteredResult.Key, new List<int> { number }, (k, v) => v.Add(number));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably mean: `(k, v) => { v.Add(number); return v; }`

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the `Filter` expected to do?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski please make that an answer and I will accept :) thanks for you help

Comment: @YacoubMassad I'm trying to fund out how to use AddOrUpdate with a list as the value in a concurrent dictionary. The example given bears little relation to my real intention. Lucas has solved it for me.

Comment: It's a simple API misuse, I don't think I can't get a good enough answer out of this ;)

Comment: ok. I'll add an answer shortly so that others can see it easily. Thanks again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Lucas Trzesniewski, for pointing out my mistake in the comments - he didn't want to post an answer.

> You probably mean: (k, v) => { v.Add(number); return v; }